# Issue with navigation bar landscape image

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios8, uinavigationbar, landscape, screen-orientation

I am in a hurry to provide iOS 8 support to my app. I have got a navigation controller based app and i have given back ground image to my navigation bar. One wired issue I found on testing my app using iOS 8 SDK (X-Code Beta-6) and iOS 8 beta version(8.0(12A4345d)) is that navigation bar landscape image is not working properly. I went on researching and found that images set to UIBarMetrics UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone is not working. On further research to found why it is so, I found that on setting 'View controller-based status bar appearance' to NO on plist, landscape image is not working. On removing it from plist or setting YES resolved the problem. Till now am not sure what is the reason behind this. Am I missing any thing ?

Answer (score 1):

In some cases that too didn't fixed the problem. What I did is on orientation change I have reset 'UIBarMetricsDefault' image with landscape image

```
if (potrait) {
    [navController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:
      [UIImage imageNamed:@"potraitImage"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
} else if (landScape) {
    [navController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:
      [UIImage imageNamed:@"landScapeImage"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```